# How to Remove Zipcode, State and Company from Magento 2.3

Tags: checkout, custom-field, zipcode, state, remove

As per the title, you can realize that its a very old and repetitive question, but actually I could not find a solid answer !!

I want your help (step by step) how to "remove/disable" the Zipcode & State & Company from my checkout page, please note that I'm using a 3rd party One Step Checkout Extension with Porto Theme + Magento 2.3

Your Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution in case when you don't need these values - hide them from the form (like display: none) and put there some random values. Then the customer will not see them and Magento continue to be happy. Better do not remove them totally if you don't want unexpected issues from Magento.

Comment: That's great... could you please clarify, what file I have to modify exactly ??